# Properly setting up an Array from Wordpress REST API in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

This is a 2 part question:

1) I am trying to take these elements from WordPress' REST API and set them into an array (`map_locations`) which I've created. Now, I've got the `$.ajax` portion of the function working (meaning when I console.log it, I see `[my_data]`, but the later half doesn't.

```
map_locations.forEach( function( map_item ) {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

I'm expecting the above to log to the console at least once, however I get nothing. The reason I have `console.log()` is just to see if I'm getting anything first. Is there something in my entire code that I have setup incorrectly? Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

2) How do I access the data within the `$.ajax` function for the media? I have tried to use the following to set it, but I error out at `['0']`

`image: post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.`

Full Code:

```
(function($) {

    var map_locations = [];
    // Works
    $.ajax( {
        url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/map-api?_embed',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function( data ) {
            // Run through a foreach loop and setup the post data.
            data.forEach( function( post ) {
                map_locations.push( {
                    // Set fields
                    id: post.id,
                    title : post.title.rendered,
                    lat: post.acf.location_post_lat,
                    lng: post.acf.location_post_long,
                    content: post.content.rendered,
                    address: post.acf.address,
                    address2: post.acf.address2,
                    city: post.acf.city,
                    state: post.acf.state,
                    zip: post.acf.zip,
                    phone: post.acf.phone,
                    website: post.acf.website,
                    cat: post['map-cat'],
                } )
            } )
        },
        cache : false
    } );

    console.log( map_locations );

    map_locations.forEach( function(post_item) {
        console.log('hi');
    } );

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) the reason which you're getting nothing in your function:

```
 map_locations.forEach( function(post_item) {
    console.log('hi');
 } );
```

is because you're calling the the `map_locations` array before the promise has been resolved, in that case you could refactor your code and call inside the promise.

2) You're taking the zero in the second square parenthesis as string this must be a number, try this:

```
image: post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into what is going on with issue number one. Would you wrap if in a doc.ready format or set a timeout? As for issue number 2, the [0] didn't seem to matter, but the issue was literally the format. I had a `.` in there at the end, where it should have been a `,`

Comment: @Ishio I think the best option if you reuse the code `map_locations` make it in a function and call it right after `data.forEach` statement, if not, copy and paste the code there.

Comment: To save on some space, and to prettify it a bit more, could I leave the function as is, and then after the `data.forEach` call to a function that'll execute? Otherwise, `$(document).ajaxSuccess` worked as well. If your solution is smarter, I will go that route. I am not 100% well versed in jQuery yet